# JWT Same Application is the Auth Server and the Application Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Hi experts I have recently explored a lot on OAuth and how JWT works. Essentially there should be an **AuthServer** that issues a token and there should be a **ServiceAPI**(Application Server) that uses the token for a **client**!!. I also understand a token is made up of 3-parts, the header, payload and signature...

Now what if I want to build an API that does both ...Authenticates and issues JWT tokens - and then provide the service afterwards..It Sounds like Basic Authentication with tokens!!

I am also unsure if the code I have written reflects this concept (that token issuer is the same as ServiceAPI). I am building a .net core 2.1 Web API following [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) article.

In the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        //Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44387/";
            options.Audience = "JWT:Issuer";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("GuidelineReader", p => {
                p.RequireClaim("[url]", "GuidelineReader");
            });
        });
    }
```

I have also added a **LoginController** that generates the token and returns it...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody]Application login)
    {
        IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
        var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var tokenString = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
            response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
        }

        return response;
    }

private string GenerateJSONWebToken(Application appInfo)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          null,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
          signingCredentials: credentials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

What is the difference in the following

- options.Authority
- options.Audience (I am thinking it is the application that sends https request)
- options.Issuer

Comment: Here I have written an article with Generate Token & Refresh token https://codepedia.info/aspnet-core-jwt-refresh-token-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> options.Authority

`Authority` is the address of the token-issuing authentication server. In your scenario the web api issue the token , so the `Authority` will be the url of web api .

> options.Audience (I am thinking it is the application that sends https request)

`Audience` represents the intended recipient of the incoming token or the resource that the token grants access to. In your scenario ,the web api is the protected resource which client will access with JWT token , web api will validate the token to check the claims/signature . So web api name/URL should be the `Audience`

> options.Issuer

`Issuer` Identifies the security token service (STS) that constructs and returns the token . In your scenario , the web api validates the user credential and return token. So  web api name/URL is the `Issuer`

Comment: Thanks for the answer ...so I think then my code is written correctly? There could be multiple Audience then, so why should i specify JWT:Issuer there?

Comment: The api would confirm the jwt token is issued by the trust STS , so it would validate the issuer claim . What do you mean by `multiple audience` ?

Comment: By Multiple I mean Any application can send an HTTPS Post/Get request to my API..so how do i know in advance who is the Audience? In example the value is given as JWT:Issuer...not sure why

Comment: @Samra If any client sends the requests(no matter get/post) to web api with token , the audience is the same- the webapi's name/url . if you want to distinguish which client sends the token , you can include a claim named `clientID` in your token , so that web api knows which client sends the request .

Comment: Thanks this makes it clear!!. I was actually thinking that the client's name/url is the audience. Now the other question was...the code that i have written means that my webAPI is the issuer as well as the service provider or do i need to change any values to reflect that?

Comment: @Samra , nothing seems need to change , but it's better to run the application and test

Comment: Thanks this helped..I have tested with postman and it successfully returns a token. I will mark your answer as the acepted answer.